# Any way to make VLC load srt files in the same directory automatically? (When they don't have the same name)

Tags: vlc-media-player, subtitles

Is there any way to make VLC automatically load srt files in the same directory of the file playing? (When they don't have the same name)

Just wondering, would make my life a bit easier.

**I use Linux [Lubuntu 14.04] and Windows 8.1, would like a solution for one or both.

Comment: Is there some reason why you choose to keep the subtitles named separately? Do you identify them in another way?

Comment: I want it to just work after placing the *.srt file in the same folder. Sometimes matching subtitle files downloaded wont have the same name.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In VLC do the following

> Tools » Preferences » Show settings: All
>   Tools » Preferences » Video » Subtitles / OSD » Subtitle autodetection fuzziness: 1

`1` means any subtitle will be loaded

[image]

<sup>Version 2.3.1.4 on Windows 7</sup>

---

I don't know for sure but I believe the Linux version offers the same option

Subtitle fuzziness numbers:

- 0 = no subtitles autodetected
- 1 = any subtitle file
- 2 = any subtitle file containing the movie name
- 3 = subtitle file matching the movie
  name with additional chars
- 4 = subtitle file matching the movie name
  exactly

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know how to do it in VLC, it can be done in [SMPlayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/) (any sub in directory, containing movie name, or matching move name), which is also open source and available for Linux and Windows.

You can find it in the Ubuntu repository, however you can also install the latest stable version adding the [project's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~rvm/+archive/smplayer).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rvm/smplayer
```

Comment: FWIW: The Windows version of SMPlayer has the same subtitle options

Answer (score 0):

**Not possible** unless the name of movie file name is part of the subtitles part name.

One could argue that there is theoretical combination: `fuzziness = 1` and `specified subtitle path(s)`, but this just does not work. This issue was reported several times, but always refused to be fixed by the developer.